# Using QList<QGraphicsItem*>

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qlist

I am using a developer defined QGraphicsScene pointer from the "dialog/mainwindow" class called wavesScene to return a QList of QGraphicsItem*'s using QGraphicsScene::items. Something seems to be wrong with my syntax, it says that the list "graphicsItemList" is never used/declared.

Here is my code, any ideas as to how I would properly implement this methodology

relevant code inside mainwindow/segyView.h

```
QGraphicsScene *wavesScene;
```

Constructor code *I think, may be called something different

```
SEGYView::SEGYView(QWidget *parent)
    :QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SEGYView)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    wavesScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->PixmapView->setScene(wavesScene);
}
```

Code inside slider_value_changed() slot

```
 QList<QGraphicsItem*> graphicsItemList(wavesScene->items());
    QGraphicsPixmapItem pixmapItem(graphicsItemList.at(0));
    QPixmap wavesPixmap = pixmapItem.pixmap();
    QPixmap wavesPixmapScaled = wavesPixmap.scaled((newSliderValue*INITIAL_WAVES_PIXMAP_X_SIZE), 1250);
    pixmapItem.setPixmap((wavesPixmapScaled));
    wavesScene->addItem(&pixmapItem);
```

relevant code inside actionOpen on triggered() slot

```
 wavesScene->addItem(pixmapGraphicsItem);
 ui->PixmapView->setScene(wavesScene);
```

Error is "graphicsItemList" was not declared in this scope
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixmapItem = graphicsItemList.at(0);

^

Comment: Try `QList<QGraphicsItem*> graphicsItemList {wavesScene->items()};` or `QList<QGraphicsItem*> graphicsItemList = wavesScene->items();`

Comment: Doesn't like either of those unfortunately

Comment: Then I think the problem can not be demonstrated with just the code provided.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the text of the exact error message. And indicate what line the error occurs on.

Comment: use `QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem = graphicsItemList.at(0);`

Comment: @drescherjm added any code involving the scene and the items and added the error message line. Tried the other line commented as well, same error unfortunately

Comment: What makes it even more strange though is that with the slider slot commented out, the program still functions and compilers. So it seems as though everything else is working fine except for those lines in the slider slot

Comment: Could it be an inclusion that I'm missing? I included <QList> and <QGraphicsItem> to troubleshoot. <QGraphicsPixmapItem> was already there.

Comment: To me this does not make a lot of sense. I don't see a reason for that to happen.

Comment: Well I'm glad that you're just as confused as I am, I was worried it was going to be something blatant. One thing to note is the pointer waves scene is in the private section of the SEGYView/MainWindow class . I'm not sure what effect this would have though considering it worked in other aspects of the code with the slider slot.